# What's the easiest way to move data from s3 to an aurora serverless v1 postgres database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm creating a dev environment for my team and I need to move some data from an s3 bucket to an aurora serverless v1 postgres database. So far I have not found a straightforward example. There is the lambda route, which requires writing and deploying code just to move a handful of csv files like in this example:

https://github.com/RekhuGopal/PythonHacks/blob/main/AWS_RDS_Arora_Serverless/Copy_s3_to_rds_arora_Serverless.py

And then there is the cryptic aws documentation that shows you how to query aurora serverless via psql, but doesn't tell you whether this option is available in aurora serverless v1:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import.html

I have been able to establish a local connection to the aurora db via the aws rds-data cli, but I haven't been able to configure the s3 extension. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 'So far I have not found a straightforward example - because going from file to database requires numerous pieces of information, crucial one being the schema you like. What is your input data, what does it look like, how does it need to look like in the database and what is the actual purpose here? You just want to query or actually want to go from file to relational DB?

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary I just want to upload a csv file from s3 into postgres for the purpose of developing and experimenting, I will build more legitimate ETL processes later on.

Comment: I would download the files to my local machine (or an EC2 instance) and use the `\copy` command from `psql`.

Comment: @kdgregory is using psql possible with a serverless v1 aurora postgres? If so, could you provide a link to an example?

Comment: Or alternatively, you could just try it.